# Can I create a cross-project source reference in redmine?

Tags: redmine

If you have two separate projects that is somehow connected. How can one make a reference to the source of the other project?

For referencing the source of your own project you use:

```
source:some/file
```

But since I want to refer to code in another project my thought was that I could write something like:

```
other_project:source:some/file
```

Anyone that knows if this is possible in some way? I have read http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineTextFormatting#Redmine-links but found no clues there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently this was [implemented in Redmine 1.2.0](http://www.redmine.org/issues/7409) (released 2011-05-30).  The syntax is exactly the one you suggested in the question, `other_project:source:some/file`, `other_project` being the project identifier.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in a couple of ways - although neither solution is particularly neat.

1. use an external html link to the other_project source code, where other-proj is the identifier for the other project.

   ```
   "other project source":http://myserver:3000/projects/other-proj/repository/entry/file.txt
   ```
2. define the source path via the parent directories, so from the source directory of your current project go up 3 directory levels before navigating back down to the repository of your other project. Note the source link needs to be inside double quotes to work. This method at least keeps the source tag at the front of the link.

   ```
   source:"../../../other-proj/repository/entry/file.txt"
   ```

Comment: Yes indeed, neither solution is particularly neat.

Answer (score 1):

The [Redmine Text Formatting](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineTextFormatting) page says the format is:

`source:repo_identifier|some/file`

Even so, the selected answer works for my version of Redmine (1.4.2), but it may have been changed in later versions. This link format was added to that wiki page on 2012-08-27, after OP asked their question.