# Cross references in source code comments

Tags: emacs, reference, navigation, comments

Sometimes when you write a program you need to refer to another part/or function in the comments. For example in the code below I could set two anchors "workaround1" and "workaround2" (in another file) in the comments, and make a note about ABC function with references to the relevant comments.

```
// this part does <<workaround1>>
a = 1;
a++;
...

// [[workaround1]] and [[file:c.java::workaround2][2]] can be removed once ABC is fixed
c = ABC();
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there best practice for such references? How professional programmers deal with it?
2. Is there a package for emacs which can facilitate navigation through a source code comments with such notes? I was thinking about org-mode extension with can work on top of (preferably any) language mode.

I'm aware about similar question on Redmine: [Can I create a cross-project source reference in redmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550960/can-i-create-a-cross-project-source-reference-in-redmine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no doubt different approaches available.  Someone will likely describe how to use `org-mode` for this, which is perhaps the most common approach. Personally, I use `linkd.el` -- simple. You can get it [*here*](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/linkd.el).

I use it in Emacs-Lisp files, but you can use it in any text file.

A header, or named destination looks like this as plain text:

```
      ;; (@* "Common helper functions")
```

That's for Lisp, where `;` begins a comment. In your case, you would use `//`, I believe.

A link to it from the same file looks like this:

```
      ;; (@> "Common helper functions")
```

A link to it from a different file looks like this:

```
      ;; (@file :file-name "foo.el" :to "Common helper functions")
```

But they are rendered using highlighting, and without the extraneous chars.

A destination looks like this (but highlighted):

```
      * Common helper functions
```

A same-file link looks like this (but highlighted as an Emacs link, and with mouseover highlighting):

```
      > Common helper functions
```

A different-file link looks like this (but highlighted as a link, with mouseover):

```
      . foo.el : Common helper functions
```

Comment: does it support references to other files? It is not quite clear from in-package description.

Comment: Yes, and I gave an example of that above: `(@file :file-name "foo.el" :to "Common helper functions")`.

Comment: See also [LinkdMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LinkdMode) and, for some other options, [CategoryNavigation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryNavigation). The main alternative seems like WikiNav, which is distributed with [button-lock](https://github.com/rolandwalker/button-lock)